# roadmap for android development

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have basic understanding of **java** and how classes works.
please guide me in the right path.

kindly give **brief** summary of **steps** that i have to follow in this journey.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this website. I find it quite useful- https://roadmap.sh/android

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link!

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first). Considering that Kotlin is the preferred language to use for Android development, I would suggest expanding your knowledge of object-oriented programming in Kotlin rather than Java.

The documentation provides links to guides/tutorials that will walk you through the basics of an Android application while also establishing proper coding practices in Kotlin. I personally find the docs very useful in this regard, as I'm currently refactoring a legacy app written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the google codelabs to learn topics, these codelabs are updated by the Android dev team use best practices. If you are just starting out I would recommend learning Kotlin over java, Kotlin is the recommend langue by the Android Dev team, Kotlin takes advantage of coroutines.

Here is the Android dev guide for beginners, I would work through these modules. I still refer to them from time to time.
https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course